# Where should the passwords file be located for nginx

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, nginx

I am following the elasticsearch nginx integration tutorial for windows. I have generated the password using openssl.

The question is what should be the extension for the passwords file and where should it be placed.

I keep getting this error message but it is very unclear to me what exactly the issue is

> C:\Program Files\nginx-1.12.1\nginx-1.12.1>nginx -s reload nginx:
>   [error] OpenEvent("Global\ngx_reload_4428") failed (2: The system
>   cannot find the file specified)

Currently, the file is present inside the configs directory

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

  upstream elasticsearch {
    server 127.0.0.1:9200;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;

    auth_basic "Protected Elasticsearch";
    auth_basic_user_file passwords;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://elasticsearch;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify full path for the password file location:

```
location / {
   auth_basic "Secure Area (or whatever description you want)";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth/nginx.passwd;
   ... (other settings)
}
```

The example above works on Unix/Linux servers running nginx. Since you're running Windows I suppose you have to specify full path like `C:\Program Files\nginx-1.12.1\nginx-1.12.1\nginx.passwd`

Depending what exactly you want to restrict you might need to place the rule inside or outside of the **location / {}** block. Supposing you need to allow full access to your server/site and only restrict let's say /private then you will add the basic auth in:

```
location /private {
...
}
```

Comment: No problem! Glad that I could help.